# filter out lines in file 2 because column values of file 2 are within the range of values in column 2 and 3 of file 1 for similar chr values

Tags: awk, filter, range

I have two files shown below that have chr from 1 to 22. I would like to use chr and pos1 pos 2 from file 1 and to filter out lines in file 2 because they have pos1 values are in between pos1 and pos2 in file 1 for a the same chr as shown below

file 1

```
chr pos1 pos2
1   2389078 2489001
1   2800001 3023010
1   2567898 2708901
3   5647956 6356191   
4   5668887 6757869
```

file 2 :

```
chr pos1
1  2460067
1  2389080
3  5508907
```

output file:

```
chr pos1
1  2460067
1  2389080
```

I have tried to run some similar solutions such as the one below:

`awk 'NR==FNR{ start[$1] = $2; end[$1] = $3; next } (FNR==1) || ( ($1 in start) && ($2 >= start[$1]) && ($2 <= end[$1]) ) ' file1 file2`

however this is only printing the first line, how can this be improved?

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in your question(in form of code) which you have put in order to solve your own problem, this is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As `chr` in `file1` duplicate, the arrays `start` and `end` in your
script are overwritten by the values with the same `chr`. Would you please try:

```
awk '
    # check if "pos" is between pos1 and pos2 in the passed "ch"
    func inrange(ch, pos) {
        for (i in chr) {
            if (chr[i] == ch && pos >= start[i] && pos <= end[i]) return 1
        }
        return 0        # no match
    }

    NR==FNR {
        if (NR > 1) {           # skip the header line
            chr[++n] = $1       # "n" works as an id
            start[n] = $2
            end[n] = $3
        }
        next
    }
    FNR==1 || inrange($1, $2)   # print the "filtered" line in file2
' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
chr pos1
1  2460067
1  2389080
```

Answer (score 0):

If the output order doesn't matter then using GNU awk for arrays of arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    chrpos[$1][$2]
    next
}
$1 in chrpos {
    for (pos in chrpos[$1]) {
        if ( ($2 <= pos) && (pos <= $3) ) {
            print $1, pos
            delete chrpos[$1][pos]
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
chr pos1
1 2389080
1 2460067
```